# Get all post IDs from current WP_Query - not just currently visible

Tags: wp-query

I want to get all post IDs from the current query. I know how to get all IDs of the current page using the following:

```
global $wp_query;
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $wp_query->posts, "ID" );
```

This will give me an array of all post IDs, but limited to the current page.

How can I get all IDs but not limited by `'posts_per_page'`. (I don't want to modify the query by changing 'posts_per_page'.)

I know that there is already information available from the global `$wp_query` such as:

We will be displaying " `. $wp_query->query_vars['posts_per_page'] .` " posts per page if possible.

We need a total of " `. $wp_query->max_num_pages .` " pages to display the results.

*Additional Details:*

I am trying to get WooCommerce product IDs and hooking into the `woocommerce_archive_description` action to do this.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I'm not sure what you'd need the IDs of all the posts to do. Your example is regarding the total _number_ of posts/products per page, which you wouldn't need the IDs for.

Comment: My end goal is to build a taxonomy filter. I want to use the post IDs from the main query to do a taxonomy look up. The post IDs array I get will be used in the args for a get_terms() request.

Comment: WooCommerce that sort of filtering built in. Use attributes on your products and you can filter with those.

Comment: I know how to filter the products. I am by hooking into ‘woocommerce_product_query’  (http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_product_query/) and modifying the query. This is not what I am trying to do here at this stage.

I want to use the post IDs of the current query to get all terms (product_tag) related to the current query. The get_terms function accepts an array of IDs to do this ($args["object_ids”]).

I’m just wondering if there is a way to get all IDs of the current query.

Comment: The current query is the same as the current page, you need a new query with different paged / posts_per_page values

Answer (score 2):

Slightly old post I know but I just hit this exact issue myself.

Given a main_query find all the post IDs for it not limited by pagination.

I have made this function to return all terms for the main wp_query.

```
/*
 * Get terms for a given wp_query no paging
 * */
function get_terms_for_current_posts($tax='post_tag',$the_wp_query=false){
    global $wp_query;
    // Use global WP_Query but option to override
    $q = $wp_query;
    if($the_wp_query){
        $q = $the_wp_query;
    }

    $q->query_vars['posts_per_page'] = 200;// setting -1 does not seem to work here?
    $q->query_vars['fields'] = 'ids';// I only want the post IDs
    $the_query = new WP_Query($q->query_vars);// get the posts
    // $the_query->posts is an array of all found post IDs
    // get all terms for the given array of post IDs
    $y = wp_get_object_terms( $the_query->posts, $tax );
    return $y;// array of term objects
}
```

Hope this helps you or someone else stumbling across this.

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to share my two cents.

Indeed, the main `$wp_query` will only return the posts correlating to the current [Pagination Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters).

Like Milo pointed out in the comments you can actually create a new query with a different set of pagination parameters (eg: `nopaging`, `posts_per_page`, `posts_per_archive_page` ...).

We can mirror the main query parameters and merge them with our new pagination parameters. As we're only interested in the posts ids, we can use the [`fields query parameter`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#return-fields-parameter) to only return the posts ids.

```
/**
 * Retrieve the IDs of the items in the main WordPress query.
 * 
 * Intercept the main query, retrieve the current parameters to create a new query.
 * Return the IDs of the items in the main query as an array.
 * 
 * @see https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/400947/190376
 * 
 * @return Array The IDs of the items in the WordPress Loop. False if $post is not set.
 * 
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
public function wpso_323280() {

    if ( is_main_query() ) {

        global $wp_query;

        $buffer_query = $wp_query->query;
    
        $args = array(
            'nopaging' => true,
            'fields' => 'ids',
        );
    
        $custom_query = new WP_Query( array_merge( $buffer_query, $args ) );
    
        wp_reset_postdata();
    
        return $custom_query->posts;

    };

}
```